# Is there a way to change the ordering of the tracks in the playlist?

Tags: deezer

I think the title is pretty clear, we can easily retrieve the playlists of the user using sdk or API but is there a way to change the order of the tracks inside the playlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily ordering your playlist tracks by using the URL http://api.deezer.com/playlist/{id}/tracks, with a POST method, and adding the required param 'order'.

You can have more informations at this page http://developers.deezer.com/api/playlist/tracks, where all actions are explained.